# Check the existence of a url - ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic

To perform a verification of a url in a development in asp use this code, I allowed to verify if some images existed on the server otherwise show another route, do not use FileExits because the images were not on the same server.

Do you know any other way?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code writing service, help us help you. See [ask].

Comment: This explanation resolves to find url in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```vb
<%
revisar_url = "http://www.tutores.org"
Response.write "<br>Revisando:<b>" & revisar_url & "</b><br>"

If comprobar_componente("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") Then 
    Select Case Revisar_esta_url(revisar_url) 
        Case 200 : Response.Write "La url Si existe."
        Case 404 : Response.Write "El sitio web existe, pero no la pagina especificada"
        Case Else : Response.Write "La url indicada ouede que no exista" 
    End Select
Else
    Response.Write "Necesitas tener instalado el componente Msxml2.XMLHTTP"
End if 

Function comprobar_componente(ProgId)
    Dim objeto_temp
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objeto_temp = Server.CreateObject(ProgId)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        comprobar_componente = True
    Else
        comprobar_componente = False
    End If

    Set objeto_temp = Nothing
End Function

Function Revisar_esta_url(strURL) 
    Dim objXML 

    Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") 
    objXML.open "GET", strURL, false 
    On error resume next
    objXML.send
    Revisar_esta_url = objXML.Status 
End Function
%>
```

Regards